# A time field instead of end date in drupal 7 date field

Tags: 7, datetime

Is it possible to have a time field (for example in minute only) instead of end date of date field in drupal 7?

so that the user select start date and time and due time (in minute) and end datetime will be start datetime + due time?

Comment: You can collect just start date and duration (select list or text fiel), then you could use yourtheme_preprocess_page() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7,  there you can get the start date and the duration and do your calculation. This is the php documentation for date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Date single day](http://drupal.org/project/date_single_day) module for Drupal 6 worked great for this use case. There isn't a 7.x version yet, but there is [an issue to port it](http://drupal.org/node/1130490).

Comment: Thanks, I wish there was a 7.x version too, maybe I port it to D7.

Comment: There is a D7 version now.